# IdentityServer 4 - Custom IExtensionGrantValidator always return invalid_grant

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

My app requirements is to authenticate using client credentials AND another code (hash).
I followed this [link](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/extension_grants.html) to create and use custom `IExtensionGrantValidator`.
I manged to invoke the custom `IExtensionGrantValidator` with approved grant, but client always gets `invalid_grant` error.

For some reason the set operation ofd `Result` (property of `ExtensionGrantValidationContext`) always fails (overriding the `Error` value returns the overrided value to client).

This is `CustomGrantValidator` Code:

```
public class CustomGrantValidator : IExtensionGrantValidator
{
    public string GrantType => "grant-name";

    public Task ValidateAsync(ExtensionGrantValidationContext context)
    {
        var hash = context.Request.Raw["hash"]; //extract hash from request
        var result = string.IsNullOrEmpty(hash) ?
            new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.InvalidRequest) :
            new GrantValidationResult(hash, GrantType);
        context.Result = result
    }
}
```

`Startup.cs` contains this line:

```
services.AddTransient<IExtensionGrantValidator, CustomGrantValidator>();
```

And finally client's code:

```
        var httpClient = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5000") };
        var disco = await httpClient.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("http://localhost:5000");

        var cReq = await httpClient.RequestTokenAsync(new TokenRequest
        {
            GrantType = "grant-name",
            Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,

            ClientId = clientId,// client Id taken from appsetting.json
            ClientSecret = clientSecret, //client secret taken from appsetting.json
            Parameters = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "hash", hash } }
        });

        if (cReq.IsError)
            //always getting 'invalid_grant' error
            throw InvalidOperationException($"{cReq.Error}: {cReq.ErrorDescription}");
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue and found the answer from @Sarah Lissachell, turn out that I need to implement the IProfileService. This interface has a method called IsActiveAsync. If you don't implement this method, the answer of ValidateAsync will always be false.

```
public class IdentityProfileService : IProfileService
{

    //This method comes second
    public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        //IsActiveAsync turns out to be true 
        //Here you add the claims that you want in the access token
        var claims = new List<Claim>();

        claims.Add(new Claim("ThisIsNotAGoodClaim", "MyCrapClaim"));

        context.IssuedClaims = claims;
    }

    //This method comes first
    public async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {           
        bool isActive = false;
        /*
            Implement some code to determine that the user is actually active 
            and set isActive to true
        */
        context.IsActive = isActive;
    }
}
```

Then you have to add this implementation in your startup page.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    // Some other code
    services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                .AddAspNetIdentity<Users>()
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(config.GetApiResources())
                .AddExtensionGrantValidator<CustomGrantValidator>()
                .AddProfileService<IdentityProfileService>();
    // More code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below codes works on my environment :

```
public async  Task ValidateAsync(ExtensionGrantValidationContext context)
{
    var hash = context.Request.Raw["hash"]; //extract hash from request
    var result = string.IsNullOrEmpty(hash) ?
        new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.InvalidRequest) :
        new GrantValidationResult(hash, GrantType);
    context.Result = result;

    return;
}
```

Don't forget to register the client to allow the custom grant :

```
return new List<Client>
    {
        new Client
        {
            ClientId = "client",

            // no interactive user, use the clientid/secret for authentication
            AllowedGrantTypes = { "grant-name" },

            // secret for authentication
            ClientSecrets =
            {
                new Secret("secret".Sha256())
            },

            // scopes that client has access to
            AllowedScopes = { "api1" }
        }
    };
```